# How to set transform-origin using VelocityJS

Tags: javascript, html, animation, velocity.js

How can I set the `transform-origin` of my tranform animation using VelocityJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can animate `transformOriginX`/`transformOriginY`/`transformOriginZ` in your `.velocity()` calls. If it's just to reset it to an initial value you can use same start and end values.